# numbering paragraph in each section

Tags: numbering

I wish to number the paragraph in each section, the number format is like (section number, paragraph number). for example

```
Section 1
1.1 subsection

1.2 subsection

(1.1) blah blah paragraph
(1.2) blah blah paragraph
(1.3) blah blah paragraph
1.3 subsection
(1.4) blah blah paragraph

Section 2
2.1 subsection
(2.1) blah blah paragraph
(2.2) blah blah paragraph
2.2 subsection
(2.3) blah blah paragraph
```

note that the prargraph number alway reset at each section.

So far my method is

```
\newcounter{parnum}
\newcommand{\N}{%
   \noindent\refstepcounter{parnum}%
    \makebox[\parindent][l]{\textbf{(\thechapter.\arabic{parnum}\space}}}
```

But apparently this method do not reset the paragraph number at each section.

How should I improve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset the paragraph number at each section, try:

```
\newcounter{parnum}[section]
\renewcommand{\theparnum}{\thechapter.\arabic{parnum}}
\newcommand{\N}{%
  \noindent\refstepcounter{parnum}%
  \makebox[\parindent][l]{\textbf{(\theparnum)\space}}}
```

Comment: Thanks **\newcounter{parnum}[section]** is exactly what I am looking for